# Copy binary file on Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have a very restricted environment. It could be a chrooted environment or a VM. It has the following basic utilities available: *bash*, *hostname*, *[ls](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ls)*, *mkdir*, *ping*, *rm*, *getent*, and *id*. The [/proc](https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=Wikipedia%20mkdir) filesystem is also available.

All others utilities, like *cp* and [cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)) are unavailable. Is it possible to copy a file with these utilities?

Comment: `rsync`,`dd`, `gcc`...

Comment: is `echo` available? You can use that to copy to another file. Give us the `ls` output of the `bin` and `sbin` directories to see what our options are.

Comment: commands listed in the question are all under /bin, /sbin directory doesn't even exist. BTW, "echo" is a bash builtin command, it's always available.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really a programming question. It might be more on topic at superuser or unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

To copy `inputfile` to `outputfile` using only `bash`:

```
echo "$(<inputfile)" >outputfile
```

(Limitation: NULs and trailing newlines will be omitted.)

Comment: Tried, it works. and trailing newlines are still kept ;)

Comment: Made further tests, it only works on text files, not binary files :(